# How to use populate with sub-doc ObjectId

Tags: mongoose

### This is JobTypeSchema

```
  const mongoose = app.mongoose;
  const JobTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true, },
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });
  // tree
  JobTypeSchema.add({
    children: [JobTypeSchema]
  })
  return mongoose.model('JobType', JobTypeSchema);
```

jobType document like this:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2caf"), 
   "name" : "catering", 
   "children" : [
       {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2cae"), 
          "name" : "chef", 
          "children" : [
             {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2cab"), // Leaf children _id
                "name" : "steak chef", 
                "children": [],
             } 
          ]
       },
       {
          "_id" : ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2cad"), 
          "name" : "waiter", 
          "children" : [
             {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2caw"), 
                "name" : "dishwasher", 
                "children": [],
             } 
          ]
       } 
   ]
}
```

> JobTypeSchema is a tree structure

### This is JobSchema

```
  const mongoose = app.mongoose;
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  const JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    salary: Number,
    jobType: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'JobType' },
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });
  return mongoose.model('Job', JobSchema);
```

> Suppose there is a piece of data like this (job document):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2ttt"), // job _id
  "name": "super Steak Chef",
  "salary": "1000",
  "jobType": ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2cab"), // JobType Leaf children _id
},
```

### When i tried the following

```
Job.findById({ 
   _id: "5ddd03e1789ce214986e2ttt" // job _id
}).lean();
```

I will get job document like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2ttt"), // job _id
  "name": "super Steak Chef",
  "salary": "1000",
  "jobType": ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2cab"), // this is JobType Leaf children _id
},
```

### JobSchema's jobType ref JobTypeSchema's leaf children _id

> When I try to populate JobType, I get **Null**
>
> How to get this result ? Thanks !
>
> **job document**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2ttt"), // job _id
  "name": "super Steak Chef",
  "salary": "1000",
  "jobType": {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5ddd03e1789ce214986e2cab"), // from JobType Leaf children _id
     "name" : "steak chef", 
     "children": [],
   }
},
```

This is a question about populate, I have a problem with my usage!
My good friends, I hope to get your help.This problem has troubled me for a long time, Thanks for everyone who helped me!

Comment: can you post your schema code as text?

Comment: ok,change it now

Comment: Your question is sitll not clear, please give sample documents for both of the models. And give the expected output.

Comment: @SuleymanSah , Thank you very much for your patient answer,  I modified the problem, please check