# mongoose populated by subdocument ID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

> Assume the following Schema:

**Aschema**

```
  ASchema = {
    type: { type: ObjectId, ref: BModel }
  }

  /**
   * ADoc = { 
   *    _id: 00a1, 
   *    type: 00b1001 
   * },
   * 
   */
```

**BSchema**

```
  BSchema = {
    children: [{ 
      name: String, 
    }]
  }

  /**
   * BDoc = { 
   *    _id: 00b1,
   *    children: [{ 
   *      _id: 00b1001,
   *      name: 'b1'
   *    }, {
   *      _id: 00b1002,
   *      name: 'b2'
   *    }]
   * }
   * 
   */
```

When I find by _id: "00a1", I will get the following results

```
  AModel.find({_id: '00a1'}).lean();
  /**
   * {
   *    _id: 00a1,
   *    type: 00b1001
   * }
   */
```

As you can see, my ASchema type ref refs the ObjectId of a subdocument in B document

I want to get this result

```
  /**
   * {
   *    _id: 00a1,
   *    type: {
   *      _id: 00b1001,
   *      name: 'b1'
   *    }
   * }
   */
```

I know there is populate, but I get null, hope to get everyone's help, thank you!

I posted the same question, but the description is not clear enough.
[How to use populate with sub-doc ObjectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212290/how-to-use-populate-with-sub-doc-objectid)

Comment: How mongoose supposed to be understand that you want the child with id 00b1001?

Comment: Thank you @SuleymanSah, mongodb sub-document have unique id. AModel's type saves B's children sub-document unique id